# vba simple for each loop through a column

Tags: vba, loops, excel, if-statement, offset

I would like some support in correcting this simple piece of code. when running the code it is always displaying 1 and then a miss match error box pops up. I cant see why this is not working the code seems simple enough.

```
 Sub Test3()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Range("D1:D10")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(cell.Value)
End If
Next cell
```

End Sub

Comment: what are you going to achieve with this line: `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(cell.Value)`?

Comment: count how many cells contain a value greater than 0. This is the start of something, which I hopefully want to develop further.

Comment: in range `Set rng = Range("D1:D10")`?

Comment: i have already set rng = range("d1:d10")

Comment: I see:) I ask you, whether you going to count how many cells are >0 in range `d1:d10`? Why not single line `MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, ">0")` without loop?

Comment: when I compile the code and hover over 'cell' it shows error 2042.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49510/discussion-between-simoco-and-user1810449)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
Sub Test3()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, IAmTheCount As Long
    Set rng = Range("D1:D10")
    IAmTheCount = 0
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value > 0 Then
            IAmTheCount = IAmTheCount + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    MsgBox IAmTheCount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `for each` loop, you are counting the cells one by one. That's why the `Msgbox` always says 1. You should not use a loop to achieve what you want

```
Sub Test3()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("D1:D10")

    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, ">0")

End Sub
```